# Getting IllegalArgumentException error in factory method after upgrading testNG version from 6.11 to 6.14.2

Tags: testng

I am accessing test context information inside factory method. When i upgrde testNG version from 6.11 to 6.14.2, i am not able to execute my tests.

```
    public class FactoryTest
    {
        @Factory
        public Object[] createInstances( ITestContext ctx ) throws Exception
        {
            XmlTest currentXmlTest = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest();
            String parameterValue = currentXmlTest.getParameter( currentXmlTest.getName() );
        }
```

Getting **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments** when i run my tests

```
    2018-03-30_13:16:43.872 ERROR c.t.p.testsupport.TestInitiator - 
org.testng.TestNGException: 
The factory method class com.polo.primetest.factories.FactoryTest.createInstances() threw an exception
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:197)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processFactory(TestNGClassFinder.java:223)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processMethod(TestNGClassFinder.java:179)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processClass(TestNGClassFinder.java:171)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:121)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:370)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:167)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:663)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at com.polo.primetest.testsupport.TestInitiator.createTestNG(TestInitiator.java:436)
    at com.polo.primetest.testsupport.TestInitiator.init(TestInitiator.java:302)
    at com.polo.primetest.execution.main.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:167)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you open an issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues with a full sample?

Comment: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1745